# Simple optional types for models in dart

Tags: dart, option-type, union-types

I'm fairly new to dart I'm looking around and I can't see any option for basic optionals, example in TypeScript.

Please look at the commented property. 'username'.

I define my model.

```
type User {
    uid: string,
    // Not chosen yet. The team knows this might be null from the '?' Might never be chosen.
    username?: string
    accountType: 'email'|'facebook' // Also no union types in Dart?
}
```

How could I achieve the same thing in Dart that would flag compile time warnings/errors?

Would also be nice if we had conditional unwrapping like user.?username for example.

Swift, Java, TypeScript, Flow, C# all have this. It's extremely handy.

Comment: Dart doesn't support union types currently. It probably will eventually. Not sure what the other parts are about exactly. "There is away to do this with classes". Also not sure what you mean by that exactly, but that's probably what you will have to use in Dart until more features become available. A main part of Dart 2 was to make it easier to add new language features and support them on all target platforms. You can follow the ongoing work on https://github.com/dart-lang/language

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for your reply. Let me rephrase. How does one simply mark properties as potentially null? For example. Java has nullable decorator. Swift has optional types '?' same as TypeScript

Comment: Non-nullability is a feature the Dart team is currently working on but it has a big impact on the language and needs to be drafted carefully. https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/110

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the reply. But how does one know what is undefined and not undefined in say a model class from a server?

Comment: There is no such thing as `undefined` in Dart. You can check for `null` or add a custom flag that holds such information and set it in custom deserialization code.

Comment: @OliverDixon JSON data would be contained in a Map, not a model class. If you want a typed class from JSON data, you'll have to construct an instance and pullout the data from the Map. All members of a class are optional in the sense that they are Nullable... just don't assign to them. Dart has conditional access (with `?.`) to cope with that. https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#classes

Comment: @ABabin the problem is we have no way to saying what is 'potentially' null, i.e what is optional when defining properties.

Comment: @OliverDixon Yes and like Gunter said, non-nullability is currently being worked on. [Here's the proposal](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/110)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer not looking for non-nullable types. I just simply want to define a model from an API that has optional properties on objects so that the team knows this and when they should check or not. Looks like it's not possible.

Comment: No, there is no such thing and not planned (to my knowledge)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that's a real shame. Are you aware if annotations work at all? It seems like we can't use this language then.

Comment: As mentioned, you would need to maintain that information on an additional property. If you need this a lot you can use code generation to write a lot of similar code (like in the json_serializable package)

Comment: Annotations can be used as parameters to code generation, but don't do anything by itself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the last 3 projects I've worked on in TS had shared model code between the client & server. This was maintained by backend, it flagged as an error to the frontend code automatically when compiling to a new API versions. Extremely handy and caught many errors. Was trying to figure out away to do this with Dart, seems impossible.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You just need to be a bit more creative.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 'A bit more creative' generally means messy solution that will never be maintained :-P

Answer (score 2):

I'd write:

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String username;
  final AccountType accountType;
  User(this.uid, this.userName, this.accountType) {
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(uid, "uid");
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(accountType, "accountType");
  }
} 
enum AccountType { email, facebook; }
```

Dart does not have non-nullable types yet, so you have to check for null manually. 
You cannot get a compile-time warning. We hope to introduce non-nullable types as the default "soonish", at which point you should be able to write `String? userName;`.
You can already use `user?.userName?.toUpperCase()` to conditionally call methods on values that may be `null`.

Dart does not have union types, but what you use here is an enumerated type, which Dart does have. They can't be as complex as, say, Java's enumerated types, but for a simple choice between two values, they're quite adequate.

Comment: By 'non-nullable types' don't you mean 'optionals?' with the '?'. Non-nullable types is something entirely different, perhaps the community has worded this wrong?

Comment: Currently all types in Dart are "nullable" - they accept `null` being assigned to them. If/when we add non-nullable types to Dart, some types will be nullable, likely written `int?`, and some will be non-nullable, like `int` (no `?`). This will be a major update of the Dart syntax because it changes the meaning of the existing `int` type.  When that happens, you can declare `uid` as `String` and `username` as `String?`, and then you won't need to do the `checkNotNull` checks yourself, the language will prevent `null` from ever being the value of  `uid`.

Comment: @TomaszWójcik Still an [ongoing discussion it seems](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22)

Comment: The answer is still correct. Non-nullable types (aka "null safety") is being actively worked on, but it's not there yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) package as code generator for data-classes/unions/pattern-matching/cloning.
For example:

```
@freezed
class MyUnion with _$MyUnion {    
    const factory MyUnion.firstType(int value) = FirstType;
    const factory MyUnion.secondType() = SecondType;
    const factory MyUnion.thirdType(String a, double b) = ThirdType;
}
....
var myObj1 = MyUnion.firstType(19);
var myObj2 = MyUnion.secondType();
var myObj3 = MyUnion.thirdType('a',10);
//
// And the magic is below:
//
myObj1.when(
    firstType: (int value) =>  .... , //will go here, and value=19. but you couldn't have the object myObj1 as referement.
    secondType: () => ... ,
    thirdType: (String a, double b) => ... ,
),
//
//or using map (in my option is nicer): 
//
myObj1.map(
    firstType: (FirstType value) => ..., //go here, and here you have myObj referement.
    secondType: (SecondType value) => ...,
    thirdType: (ThirdType value) => ...,
),
```

**But you can use pattern matching included in Dart 3**

```
switch(myObj1) {
    FirstType(:final value) => ..., // value =19
    SecondType() => ...,  
    ThirdType(:final b) => ..., // here only interested in b=10  
}
```

But in **dart vers.3** Google added also the **sealed** classes that works as follow: you can declare an abstract class as **sealed** and then define all different types as different hinerited classes .

The dart compiler knows, because of the sealed keyword, that all subclasses are defined in your current package, thus it is sure that all different hinerited classes are defined all there.

Knowing that, dart will let you to use the **switch** construct to "map" all the different types , because they are all in the same package (the switch can be  "exhaustive" of all different types).
Take a look  :[Medium article Dart sealed](https://medium.com/@aliammariraq/sealed-classes-in-dart-unlocking-powerful-features-d8dba185925f)

So, let me rewrite your code in dart "mode":

```
@freezed 
class Account with _$Account{
    const factory Account.email() = Email,
    const factory Account.facebook() = Facebook,
     } 

@freezed 
class User with _$User {
    const factory User({required String uid, 
                        @Default('Your default') String? username, 
                        required Account account, } ) =_User;
 } 

}
//
//.....
//
var user = User( uid : '_____', username: '____', account: Account.email() );
// ...
switch(user) {
    case (Email e) : {
    }
    case (Facebook f) : {
        }
    default { }
    }
```